# How to simply turn heating on/off with VRT 340f thermostat?

Tags: heating, thermostat

I've just moved into a new house and it has a Valiant boiler with a VRT 340f thermostat and I have to say it is completely perplexing even after having read the manual several times!

It seems entirely geared around scheduling heating but all I want is to have the heating off by default and then turn it on/off on-demand!

How can I achieve this with this indecipherable thermostat?

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed the manual for your VRT 340f thermostat online. It does not appear that this unit is intended for use in a simple on/off on demand mode. From the description in the manual it appears that unit is intended to be operated on a schedule.

Your most logical choice may be to replace the thermostat with a different model that offers the simple level of control that you desire. Since this thermostat communicates with the heater unit using a radio link your choices of replacement unit are going to be limited to what is compatible with the heater.